# Azure Devops Copy Task couldn't find the dist/app folder after npm task build

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops

I'm deploying and angular app on Azure App Service. The release pipeline succeeded but the app is not there. I looked into wwwroot and LocalSiteRoot the dist folder is not there. Is my pipeline wrong? based on the app angular.json that the build will be generated in dist/myapp. But the **Copy Task** couldn't find it.

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 6.x'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Use npm @latest'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install -g npm@latest'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@0
  displayName: 'npm build'
  inputs:
    cwd: myapp/package.json
    command: custom
    arguments: 'run prod-build-dev'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)/dist/myapp'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: app'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: app
```

Comment: Try my solution that I answered for a similar/related question [dist folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69262068/13797046).

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Devops Copy Task couldn't find the dist/app folder after npm task build

To make sure the build will be generated in `dist` folder, you should set the `package.json` and `angular.json` files correctly.

The `package.json` file like:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prod-build-dev": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer",
    "prod-build-staging": "ng build --prod --configuration=staging --build-optimizer"
  }
```

And do not change the default `outputPath` in the `angular.json`:

```
  "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
       }
```

There is a great document about [Deploy Angular App Using Azure DevOps Build and Release Pipelines](https://medium.com/better-programming/deploy-angular-app-using-azure-devops-build-and-release-pipelines-f7f77ca28be4), you could check it for some more details.

If above not help you, you could share your `package.json` and `angular.json` files and the build log about `npm build` task in your question. I will check it.

Hope this helps.