# dist folder on basic vue.js

Tags: vue.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I created a basic vue.js with Visual studio 2019. I put it on a git in my private azure server. I have a windows build agent.

yml for building, no error.

```
trigger:
- master

pool: 'Default'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

I tried somes "copy/archive files" commands.
One of them

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/VuejsApp1'
  inputs:
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/VuejsApp1'
```

Every method seems to show that the dist folder is never created.

similar question : [why is azure build pipeline not generating a dist folder for an angular build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63175655/why-is-azure-build-pipeline-not-generating-a-dist-folder-for-an-angular-build)

---

> ##[section]Starting: npm install and build
> ============================================================================== Task         : Command line Description  : Run a command line script
> using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows Version      :
> 2.151.1 Author       : Microsoft Corporation Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
> ============================================================================== Generating script.
> ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
> ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\DevOpsAgent_work_temp\2d81f910-5c00-4330-9d13-27c8c30aa7a0.cmd""
>
> > yorkie@2.0.0 install C:\DevOpsAgent_work\171\s\node_modules\yorkie
> > node bin/install.js
>
> CI detected, skipping Git hooks installation
>
> > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\DevOpsAgent_work\171\s\node_modules\core-js
> > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> Thank you for using core-js (‌
> https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ‌) for
> polyfilling JavaScript standard library!‌
>
> The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on
> Open Collective or Patreon: ‌ >‌
> https://opencollective.com/core-js ‌ >‌
> https://[www.patreon.com](http://www.patreon.com)/zloirock ‌
>
> Also, the author of core-js (‌
> https://github.com/zloirock ‌) is looking for a good
> job -)‌
>
> > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\DevOpsAgent_work\171\s\node_modules\ejs
> > node ./postinstall.js
>
> Thank you for installing ‌EJS‌: built with the ‌Jake‌ JavaScript build
> tool (‌https://jakejs.com/‌)‌
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13
> (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
> notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
> fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
> DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13
> (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
> notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
> fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
> DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3:
> wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> added 1488 packages from 822 contributors and audited 1492 packages in
> 71.233s
>
> 44 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 6 vulnerabilities (1 low, 3 moderate, 2 high)   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
> ##[section]Finishing: npm install and build

Comment: Please add logs of steps `npm install and build` and `Copy files`. Also add `- script: ls` after `npm install and build'`.

Comment: I edit the post for logs. Is is for linux, never done dir on azure. I begins with nde, maybe I need to install node too in the yml, default microsoft script crashed so I tought I didnt need it when the build didnt crash.

Comment: dir command show me that i really not have dist folder. just my git things and node_modules

Comment: Ok. But logs look like log of `npm install` and what about `npm run build`?

Comment: my script do both, logs is for both.

Comment: As Jane suggested check it locally, because in logs nothing indicates that `npm run build` was run. Please ensure that it works locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to NOT do install and build on the same "script".

```
- script: 'npm install'
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: 'npm run build'
  displayName: 'Build project'
```

after that, you can get the dist folder

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, I've spent few hours trying to find answer same problem I have with build for React.JS

Answer (score 0):

There are two troubleshooting advice:

1.Try to build locally, or **run the npm command using the PowerShell task** of Azure DevOps to see if the same issue exists.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      npm install
      npm run build
```

2.Check if the `options` parameter in your json file is set to `dist`.

```
  "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
       }
```

Comment: I didn't have time to test your powershell version, If you want to add a sample for another one, could be usefull.

Comment: I need to explore the json, I never change outputpath